# Passing Component Attribute to Visualforce Page

Tags: lightning

I need to allow a user to save or print a PDF from a component.  My understanding is that I need to utilize a Visualforce Page and embed the component into that page.  I have that in place but I'm unsure how to pass the attribute (a list of records) so that they populate the datatable in the component via the visualforce page.  Here is what I have:

The attribute is

Action to launch the visualforce page:

```
PrintTable : function(component, event, helper) {
var url = location.origin + '/apex/GroupStructureListPrint'
    ; 
window.open(url, '_self');
    console.log("### Im in the PrintPageAction");
},
```

Application:

```
<aura:application access="global" extends="ltng:outApp" >
 <aura:dependency resource="c:GroupStructureListPDF"/>
```

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page >
<apex:includeLightning />
```

I am in the GroupStructureListPDF

```
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:GroupStructureListPrint", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:GroupStructureListPDF",
          { 
      },
      "lightning",
      function(cmp) {
        // do some stuff
          //     console.log('This message is from visualforce function');
          //   console.log('Data which is coming from lightning component',event.getParam('data'));
          //debugger;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! thanks!

Fred

Comment: Are you saying you need to pass list of records from VF to Lightning Component? If yes, then take a look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/230579/54851) and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm actually looking to pass the list of records from the component where I launch the visualforce page to the visualforce page.  I'm on a lighting component that has a datatable.  I want to print that datatable so I click a button which launches the visualforce page that has the same component inside of it.  Thanks!